# C++ Unit testing - using hardcoded or generated array

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

Let's say I'writing c++ driver for controlling some device on the serial bus. This is simplified version of the problem.
I have class `DeviceDriver` that have `std::vector<unsigned char> transmitFrames(int deviceNumber)` method. It returns two significant bytes followed by constant number of zero values. The pattern is:

`transmitFrames(0)` should return `{0xFF, 0xFF}`,
`transmitFrames(1)` should return `{0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00}`,
`transmitFrames(2)` should return `{0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}`...

When testing this method should I use hardcoded expected arrays or should I generate it somewhere?
Hardcoded version it's nearly impossible to write because `transmitFrames(100)` will return the vector of many values. Generated version would be okay but what about algorithm? It will be the same as in the class. This would break DRY rule and of course testing algorithm would have still bug. I'm using googletest framework. How to deal with problems like long arrays in unit testing?

Comment: Do you even need to generate an array?  Can't you just make sure the first two elements are what you want, and loop through the rest to make sure they are all zero?

Comment: That's right. But what about the situation (not mentioned in the question) when this two values should be in the middle of the Vector. Should i check only if particular number od zeroes and after are?

Comment: loop over all indices that should be zero to confirm, then check the two that should not be.

Comment: If you don't care about order, you can use `IsSupersetOf(std::vector(0, n))` and then `IsSupersetOf({the, actual, non, zero, values})` (and maybe `SizeIs()` to make sure there are no more extra elements).

Comment: It would be great if the matcher would take care about the order.

Comment: You could count the numbers of `0xFF` and `0x00` in the vector. I would personally use small hardcoded arrays to unit test. According to your question, there is no need to have a `transmitFrames(100)` call for a unit test (unless the resulting vector depends on the size, of course).